# How is Docker different from Vagrant or virtualization? How can I use it to mass-deploy an OS?

Tags: docker

I'm having a tough time grasping what Docker is. It seems like another command-line virtualization app like Vagrant. But I've heard it can be used to mass-deploy an image to several VPSs. How, though?

Comment: For the differences between docker and vagrant, do some google may help. For mass deploy, you can push your custom image to docker repository(aka registry) which is centralized.

Comment: @jasonz My own hosted repository? (I wouldn't want the image to be public)

Comment: You can host your private repository using https://github.com/docker/distribution.